# Looping on child AbstractControl list within FormGroup in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Here's the code of a component that tries to determine whether each `AbstractControl` within a `FormGroup` is `pristine` before displaying a validation error:

```js
export class FieldErrorsComponent {
  @Input() control: AbstractControl | FormGroup;

  public controlsAreNotPristine(): boolean {
    if (this.control instanceof FormGroup) {
      return ((this.control as FormGroup).controls.every(control => !control.pristine));
    }
  }
}
```

This, of course, does not work because `FromGroup.controls` is defined as follows:

`controls: { [key: string]: AbstractControl; };`

I don't know what a good alternative to loop on `controls` would be? The real problem is that `FormGroup.pristine` does not really reflect the value of the sum of its child controls, which I understand might be made so by design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FormGroup` doesn't provide any iterator as [can be seen from its interface](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup). But it provides access to controls which are defined like this:

```
controls: {[key: string]: AbstractControl}
```

So you can use standard `for in` loop to iterate over them:

```
  public controlsAreNotPristine(): boolean {
    if (this.control instanceof FormGroup) {
      const controls = (this.control as FormGroup).controls
      for (const name in controls) {
         if (controls[name].pristine) {
            return true;
         }
      }
       return false;
    }
  }
```

> The real problem is that FormGroup.pristine does not really reflect
>   the value of the sum of its child controls, which I understand might
>   be made so by design.

FormGroup should correctly reflect the state of its child controls. This can be seen from the `_updatePristine` method on FormGroup:

```
  _updatePristine(opts: {onlySelf?: boolean} = {}): void {
    this._pristine = !this._anyControlsDirty(); <------- ensure all controls are pristine

    if (this._parent && !opts.onlySelf) {
      this._parent._updatePristine(opts);
    }
  }
```

Comment: OMG, of course. Why was I trying to complicate things :(

Comment: So, what I meant was, I want to show the error only if *all* controls within `FormGroup` are *not* pristine.

Comment: just remove `!` then - `if (form[name].pristine) {`, updated the answer

Comment: Actually I'm getting an error: cannot assign to name because it's a constant or readonly property.

Comment: Might you be missing a `const` just before `name`?

Comment: yeah, or use `let` - `for (let name in form) {`